# have one compile directives with two directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs, directive, angular-directive

I have one compile directive in my application code and have tow directive depend on that compile my code is here :

```
app.directive('compile', ['$compile', function ($compile) {
      return function(scope, element, attrs) {
          var ensureCompileRunsOnce = scope.$watch(
            function(scope) {
               // watch the 'compile' expression for changes
              return scope.$eval(attrs.compile);
            },
            function(value) {

              element.html(value);

              $compile(element.contents())(scope);
             ensureCompileRunsOnce();
            }
        );
    };
}]);
```

and here is my two directives

```
app.directive('heatMap',['$compile',function($compile){

     return {
        // Restrict it to be an attribute in this case
        restrict: 'A',
        // responsible for registering DOM listeners as well as updating the DOM
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {             
            $(element).treefy(scope.$eval(attrs.heatMap));

        }
    };


}]);

app.directive('basicLine',['$compile',function($compile){

     return {
        // Restrict it to be an attribute in this case
        restrict: 'A',
        // responsible for registering DOM listeners as well as updating the DOM
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {             
            $(element).highcharts(scope.$eval(attrs.basicLine));                    
        }
    };


}]);
```

basicLine directive works curectly but another directive doesnt work where i go wrong? i use  in my html and use `$sce.trustAsHtml("<div id='treemap' heat-map='config'></div>")` and `$sce.trustAsHtml("<div id="basic" basic-Line='config'></div>");` in my javascript code 
but treemap doesnt work

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? Is there an error? What do you mean by two directives _depend_ on compile directive? At least from the code, I see no dependency. What is `$eval("config")` return? Explain clearly what doesn't work. Provide code in plunker, if needed. Clarify what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: doesnt show the chart both of the element must show chart but one of them just work ,  basic-line work another one doesnt work , nothing return the directive may not call in heat-map

Comment: Provide a plunker and people could try to help you debug this.

Comment: it's part of big project i cant make plunker

Comment: You should be reduce your code to reproduces the problem on your own. In fact, when you try to do so, you will, in all likelihood, find the issue on your own. From the code you provided it is not clear what happens, let alone why it doesn't work